# Erro QueryException could not find driver - Laravel - pgsql

Tags: php, laravel

Esse erro aparece e não consigo resolver. Já descomentei as linhas dos php.ini. Fiz de tudo...(usando pgsql)

> [image: Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço]

Comment: Já resolvi. Na vdd o erro sumiu do nd. Se pa pq eu n tinha reiniciado o wamp

Comment: Só para complemento: O erro não sumiu do nada. Quado você reiniciou o WampServer, o PHP recarregou as alterações do arquivo `php.ini` (ou seja, ele habilitou o *driver pgsql*)